# response.sendRedirect doesn't keep track of ip

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, response.redirect

i have a redirect on login.jsp to index.jsp with this syntax:

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

on the server when I'm accessing on localhost:8080 testing the application it works fine.
when I'm browsing remotely from another PC, and i need that server address (like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080) that redirect sends me to localhost:8080/index.jsp which of course doesn't exist on local machine. If i write something like

```
response.sendRedirect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/index.jsp");
```

then the browser loses the session variables, which i do not want.
how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try using requestDispatcher.forward() instead of response.sendRedirect()..

This will work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
response.sendRedirect("/yourWebContext/index.jsp");
```

this will work

> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/index.jsp

looses the session may be because browser doesn't send the cookie it has recieved for the with different domain name